# Inno setup install website not in Root

Tags: iis, installation, inno-setup

I have created an installer for a classic asp website.
I managed to install website in my "Root" (Default Web Site) ok.
But I would like to install website under "Sites" but not in "Root" for exmaple in an existing "Demo" site.

Any idea? 
I think the key is in line:

```
WebRoot := WebServer.GetObject('IIsWebVirtualDir', 'Root');
```

Some code I used to add the website to IIS "Root" in case is needed:

```
if (IISOptionsPage.Values[1] <> '') then begin
  IISDefAppPool := IISOptionsPage.Values[1];
end else begin
  IISDefAppPool := ExpandConstant('{#IISDefaultAppPool}');  
end;

{ Create the main IIS COM Automation object }
try
  IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
except
  RaiseException('IIS is not installed?.'#13#13'(Error: ''' + GetExceptionMessage );
end;

{ Connect to the IIS server }

WebSite := IIS.GetObject('IIsWebService', IISServerName + '/w3svc');
WebServer := WebSite.GetObject('IIsWebServer', IISServerNumber);
WebRoot := WebServer.GetObject('IIsWebVirtualDir', 'Root');

WebAppName := ExtractLastDir(ExpandConstant('{app}'));

{ (Re)create a virtual dir }

try
  WebRoot.Delete('IIsWebVirtualDir', WebAppName);
  WebRoot.SetInfo();
except

end;

VDir := WebRoot.Create('IIsWebVirtualDir', WebAppName); 
VDir.AccessRead := True;
VDir.AccessScript := True;
VDir.AppFriendlyName := WebAppName;
VDir.AspEnableParentPaths := True;
VDir.Path := ExpandConstant('{app}');

try
  VDir.AppPoolId := IISDefAppPool;
except
  MsgBox('AppPool not set.'#13#13'(Error: ''' + GetExceptionMessage, mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;

try
  VDir.AppCreate(True);
except
  MsgBox('App not created.'#13#13'(Error: ''' + GetExceptionMessage, mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;

try
  VDir.SetInfo();
except
  MsgBox('Info no set.'#13#13'(Error: ''' + GetExceptionMessage, mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert on COM automation objects but what about passing 'Sites\' as parameter in:

```
VDir := WebRoot.Create('IIsWebVirtualDir', 'Sites\' + WebAppName);
```

Is it possible to create subdirs in WebRoot.Create? I think it is worth the try :)

Or the second idea, passing 'Sites' in:

```
WebRoot := WebServer.GetObject('IIsWebVirtualDir', 'Sites');
```